# Add and save a text field in WooCommerce customer order detail pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

I have been able to add a custom text input field, in woocommerce's order details page, but I can't save the data submitted data.

This is the code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_details_before_order_table', 'add_custom_Field',10,2 );
function add_custom_Field( $order_id) {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    $order_id = method_exists( $order, 'get_id' ) ? $order->get_id() : $order->id;
    ?>
<form method="post">
     <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
        <label for="custom_URL"><?php _e( 'URL', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
        <input type="text" name="custom_URL" id="custom_URL" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $order_id->custom_URL ); ?>" />
    </p>
        <input type="submit" name="test" id="test" value="RUN" /><br/>
</form>
<?php

function submit()
{
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'custom_URL', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['custom_URL'] ) );
    echo "Your function on button click is working";
}

   if(array_key_exists('test',$_POST)){
       submit();
    }
}
```

Do you know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will allow you to add a user custom field to customer order detail and to save its value on submission:

```
// Display user custom field
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_details_before_order_table', 'add_user_custom_url_field_to_order' );
function add_user_custom_url_field_to_order( $order ) {
    global $current_user;

    $custom_url = get_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'custom_URL', true );
    ?>
    <form method="post">
         <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
            <label for="custom_URL"><?php _e( 'URL', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
            <input type="text" name="custom_URL" id="custom_URL" value="<?php echo $custom_url; ?>" />
        </p>
        <input type="submit" name="submit-custom_URL" value="<?php _e('RUN', 'woocommerce'); ?>" /><br/>
    </form>
    <?php
}

// Save the field as custom user data
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'save_user_custom_url_field_from_order' );
function save_user_custom_url_field_from_order() {
    global $current_user;

    if( isset($_POST['custom_URL']) ){
        update_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'custom_URL', sanitize_url( $_POST['custom_URL'] ) );
        wc_add_notice( __("Submitted data has been saved", "woocommerce") );
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

Note based on your comment:

If the custom url has to be different for each order, you can't save it as user meta data, but instead as $order item meta data... But the code will be slightly different and you will need to define how will be your custom urls.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but i think i didn't explained very well my need.

The custom url have to be different related to the order id (ex. 100 order, 100 different custom url). Right now the custom url are related to the user id.

Thanks a lot again! (you are saving my life!)

Comment: Hi, i followed your suggestion and I just posted another thread. If you can help me there:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62779061/in-woocommerce-order-page-create-a-custom-text-field-related-to-order-id

Thanks again